# Problem returning a value in function python

Tags: python, datetime

I´m trying to return the current time but for some reason I cant. I return this:

```
<function getHorarioActual at 0x000001E292E53950>
```

My function is quite simple

```
def getHorarioActual():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    horaActual = now.hour
    minutoActual = now.minute
    auxiliar = str(horaActual)+":"+str(minutoActual)
    horarioActual = auxiliar

    return horarioActual
```

Comment: Please include your call to `getHorarioActual`

Comment: You aren't *calling* the function. Also you can just return the expression, both auxiliar and the reassignment to horarioActual are pointless.

Comment: You also don't need to do this from scratch. Just use `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")`.

Comment: Variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` convention, not `camelCase` or anything else. Please see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more. Also, this doesn't look like it's your full code. Can you share a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all that variables to format the time in `HH:MM`. Your function can be defined just as:

```
from datetime import datetime

def getHorarioActual():
    return datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
```

Here is a proof of concept:

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:16:48) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> def getHorarioActual():
...     return datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
... 
>>> getHorarioActual()
'19:05'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are apparently not calling the function properly, writing

```
x = getHorarioActual
```

rather than

```
x = getHorarioActual()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

def getHorarioActual():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    horaActual = now.hour
    minutoActual = now.minute
    auxiliar = str(horaActual)+":"+str(minutoActual)
    horarioActual = auxiliar

    return horarioActual

t = getHorarioActual()
print(t)
```